# Deleting a dynamic member through a destructor causes program to hang

Tags: c++, vector, copy

This is my main working class that does all the high level operations:

```
class Image
{
public:
    Image();
    Image(const Image& copy);
    ~Image();

    void loadimage(string filename);
    void saveimage(string filename);
    Image superimpose(const Image& ontop, Color mask);

    int getwidth();
    int getheight();
    Image operator=(const Image&);

protected:    
    vector< vector<Color> > pixels;
    int width;
    int height;
    ImageLoader* loader;
};
```

It has a copy constructor:

```
Image::Image(const Image& copy)
{
    width = copy.width;
    height = copy.height;
    loader = copy.loader;

    pixels = copy.pixels;
}
```

and an overloaded operator= method:

```
Image Image::operator=(const Image& other)
{   
    width = other.width;
    height = other.height;
    loader = other.loader;

    pixels = other.pixels

    // Return this instance
    return *this;
}
```

The destructor is:

```
Image::~Image()
{
    delete loader;
}
```

The loadimage() method created a new dynamically allocated loader to appear:

```
if(magic_number == "P3")
{
    loader = new P3Loader;
}
else if (magic_number == "P6")
{
    loader = new P6Loader;
}
else
{
    exit(1);  // If file is of an inappropriate format
}
```

When I run the program, it hangs.

**EDIT:**  The post has been edited to reflect the problem.  Refer to Praetorian's solution that fixed the problem.

Comment: `a = b;` means you're copying the contents of `b` to `a`. You want `b = a;`

Comment: @Praetorian It's a typo.  Either one doesn't work.  Fixed the typo.

Comment: And what does *doesn't work* mean? Compiler error? Incorrect results after the copy? If it's the latter, then post what the contents of both `a` and `b` are after the copy. You have a `vector<vector<int>>` which is absolutely copyable.

Comment: The program never executes, it just hangs. Then I get RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 1m 3s).  I'm trying to implement the copying in my copy constructor and operator= overload method.  Everything in the program works like a charm, until I try to use the copy constructor or the overloaded = method on the objects that have these vectors as part of them.

Comment: You need to post your class definition, and how you're implementing the copy constructor and assignment operator. The `vector<vector<int>>` member is not your problem, or at least the problem is not what you're thinking it is. If I had to guess, since the copy constructor and assignment operator are involved, I'd say the most likely cause is you're not performing a deep copy of some other resource your class is managing.

Comment: @Praetorian Refer to the edited text.

Comment: For future reference, since your class manages a resource you should understand [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't posted how the `Image::loader` member gets initialized, but I'm assuming it is something like this:

```
Image::Image()
: loader(nullptr)
{
  // do stuff
  // then initialize loader
  loader = new ImageLoader(...);
}
```

Similarly, the definition of `~Image()` is missing, so I'm making another assumption:

```
Image::~Image()
{
  delete loader;
}
```

In the copy constructor (and assignment operator) you're simply copy the pointer from the other `Image` object, so that both `loader` members now point to the same `ImageLoader` object. When the destructor of the first object runs it'll `delete` the `ImageLoader` object, and the destructor of the second object will then attempt to `delete` the same object again. This double deletion is undefined behavior, and is probably why your program crashes.

You need to make a deep copy of the `ImageLoader` object within the copy constructor and assignment operators. It'll probably look like this:

```
loader = new ImageLoader(*other.loader); // invokes ImageLoader's copy ctor
```

Comment: You're absolutely right.  The destructor and copying of the address rather than contents was the problem.